# KeyError when Assigning value using For Loop by Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a long list of data, that meaningful data being sandwiched between 0 values, here is how it looks like

```
0
0
1
0
0
2
3
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
```

The length of 0 and meaningful value sequence is variable. I want to extract the meaningful sequence, each of them into a row in a dataframe. For example, the above data can be extracted to this:

```
1
2   3   1
1
```

I used this code to 'slice' the meaningful data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, 10000),columns = ['DT01', 'DT02', 'DT03', 'DT04', 'DT05', 'DT06', 'DT07', 'DT08', 'DT02', 'DT09', 'DT10', 'DT11', 'DT12', 'DT13', 'DT14', 'DT15', 'DT16', 'DT17', 'DT18', 'DT19', 'DT20',])
a = 0
b = 0
n=0

for n in range(0,999999):
    if raw.iloc[n].values > 0:
        df.iloc[a,b] = raw.iloc[n].values
        a=a+1
        if raw [n+1] == 0:
            b=b+1
            a=0
```

but I keep getting KeyError: n, while n is the row after the first row has a value different than 0.

Where is the problem with me code? And is there any way to improve it, in term of speed and memory cost?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['Group'] = df['col'].eq(0).cumsum()
df = df.loc[ df['col'] != 0]

df = df.groupby('Group')['col'].apply(list)
print (df)

Group
2          [1]
4    [2, 3, 1]
8          [1]
Name: col, dtype: object
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Group')['col'].apply(list).values.tolist())
print (df)
   0    1    2
0  1  NaN  NaN
1  2  3.0  1.0
2  1  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I'm trying all the solution, I will let you know if I have any problem, thank a ton!

Comment: I got KeyError 'col' while using the first code, and Group error while using the second one, what I'm missing here?

Comment: My input dataframe has `col` as column name `df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : [0,0,1,0,0,2,3,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]})`. So need only change it.

Comment: If column name is `0` then `df['col']` can be changed to `df[0]` or `df['0']` - if `0` is int or string

Comment: oh right, I'm so silly, it works like a charm now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this outputs a dataframe:

```
df.groupby(df[0].eq(0).cumsum().mask(df[0].eq(0)),as_index=False)[0]\
  .apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack(1)
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  3.0  1.0
2  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Or a string:

```
df.groupby(df[0].eq(0).cumsum().mask(df[0].eq(0)),as_index=False)[0]\
  .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str)))
```

Output:

```
0        1
1    2 3 1
2        1
dtype: object
```

Or as a list:

```
df.groupby(df[0].eq(0).cumsum().mask(df[0].eq(0)),as_index=False)[0]\
  .apply(list)
```

Output:

```
0          [1]
1    [2, 3, 1]
2          [1]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I'm trying all the solution, I will let you know if I have any problem, thank a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Try this , I break down the steps

```
df.LIST=df.LIST.replace({0:np.nan})
df['Group']=df.LIST.isnull().cumsum()
df=df.dropna()
df.groupby('Group').LIST.apply(list)
Out[384]: 
Group
2              [1]
4        [2, 3, 1]
8              [1]
Name: LIST, dtype: object
```

---

Data Input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'LIST' : [0,0,1,0,0,2,3,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]})
```

Comment: I'm trying all the solutions, I will let you know if I have any problem, thank a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with packing your original data into a pandas dataframe (in real life, you will probably use `pd.read_csv()` to generate this dataframe):

```
raw = pd.DataFrame({'0' : [0,0,1,0,0,2,3,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]})
```

The default index will help you locate zero spans:

```
s1 = raw.reset_index()
s1['index'] = np.where(s1['0'] != 0, np.nan, s1['index'])
s1['index'] = s1['index'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0).astype(int)
s1[s1['0'] != 0].groupby('index')['0'].apply(list).tolist()
#[[1], [2, 3, 1], [1]]
```

Comment: I'm trying all the solution, I will let you know if I have any problem, thank a ton!